# How to center google maps on users ip address using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
//Using the Google Maps API to create the map.
var myLatlngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(54.080743,-2.482910);
var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlngCenter,
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
```

At the minute, this how my javascript looks and it centers the map on the `new google.maps.LatLng(54.080743,-2.482910);`

Is there something I can put inside `()` to center the map on the users ip address.

Comment: Google for "GeoIP" and note that it's highly inaccurate. Modern browsers have a geolocation API but it requires you to request the user's permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the lon, lat from the IP so you have a few options

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php is a useful resource for this

A javascript example of using that is here (from there site)

```
function geolocate(timezone, cityPrecision, objectVar) {

      var api = (cityPrecision) ? "ip-city" : "ip-country";
      var domain = 'api.ipinfodb.com';
      var url = "http://" + domain + "/v3/" + api + "/?key=<your_api_key>&format=json" + "&callback=" + objectVar + ".setGeoCookie";
      var geodata;
      var callbackFunc;
      var JSON = JSON || {};

      // implement JSON.stringify serialization
      JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function (obj) {
        var t = typeof (obj);
        if (t != "object" || obj === null) {
          // simple data type
          if (t == "string") obj = '"'+obj+'"';
            return String(obj);
        } else {
        // recurse array or object
          var n, v, json = [], arr = (obj && obj.constructor == Array);
          for (n in obj) {
            v = obj[n]; t = typeof(v);
            if (t == "string") v = '"'+v+'"';
            else if (t == "object" && v !== null) v = JSON.stringify(v);
            json.push((arr ? "" : '"' + n + '":') + String(v));
          }
          return (arr ? "[" : "{") + String(json) + (arr ? "]" : "}");
        }
      };

      // implement JSON.parse de-serialization
      JSON.parse = JSON.parse || function (str) {
        if (str === "") str = '""';
          eval("var p=" + str + ";");
          return p;
      };

      //Check if cookie already exist. If not, query IPInfoDB
      this.checkcookie = function(callback) {
        geolocationCookie = getCookie('geolocation');
        callbackFunc = callback;
        if (!geolocationCookie) {
          getGeolocation();
        } else {
          geodata = JSON.parse(geolocationCookie);
          callbackFunc();
        }
      }

      //API callback function that sets the cookie with the serialized JSON answer
      this.setGeoCookie = function(answer) {
        if (answer['statusCode'] == 'OK') {
          JSONString = JSON.stringify(answer);
          setCookie('geolocation', JSONString, 365);
          geodata = answer;
          callbackFunc();
        }
      }

      //Return a geolocation field
      this.getField = function(field) {
        try {
          return geodata[field];
        } catch(err) {}
      }

      //Request to IPInfoDB
      function getGeolocation() {
        try {
          script = document.createElement('script');
          script.src = url;
          document.body.appendChild(script);
        } catch(err) {}
      }

      //Set the cookie
      function setCookie(c_name, value, expire) {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expire);
        document.cookie = c_name+ "=" +escape(value) + ((expire==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate.toGMTString());
      }

      //Get the cookie content
      function getCookie(c_name) {
        if (document.cookie.length > 0 ) {
          c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
          if (c_start != -1){
            c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1;
            c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
              c_end=document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
          }
        }
        return '';
      }
    }
```

You will need an api key but then good to go

You could also consider using HTML5  geolocation much easier https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation